# How to validate two email inputs are the same in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I have a visual flow screen with two `Email` inputs and I'd like to validate that the values are the same.

Annoyingly `Email` does not have any `Validate Input` settings, so I changed the second input into a `Text` input and added a validation formula:

```
{!Email.value}=={!Email_Confirmation}
```

But it does not fire when the values are different.

In fact, the validation never fails, and the validation message is never displayed.

**Question**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I validate two emails are the same within Visual Flow?

Cross-posted onto Chatter: [Lightning Flows - Partner Development](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000LiRu&fId=0D54V00005246C9)

Answer (score 2):

you can add a message and then set the visibility only when the two email addresses are the same.

Here is what I tried quickly -

**Two Emails and Text Message**
[image: Two Emails and Text Message]

**Text Message Visibility Criteria**
[image: Text Message Visibility Criteria]

**Screen when the emails are different**
[image: Screen when the emails are different]

**Screen when the emails are the same**
[image: Screen when the emails are the same]

Comment: Thanks Sudipta - how do you stop the user from progressing to the next screen?

Comment: You can hide the flow footer and then add your own lwc component which will do this check and accordingly set the button visibility as well. Here is the Salesforce documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation

Comment: Thanks, but if I need a custom LWC to do a simple email comparison validation it's getting a little ridiculous... :-)

Comment: I know but I don't think we have any other option. Let's see if others are having any better solution.